# Java Socket - passing int through object stream?

Tags: java, sockets, stream

I am working on Java streams,
In server side I'm trying to send int through objectOutputStream and recieve it in client side. However I am not receiving anything in client side.

Here is the server side sending int

```
public static int PLAYER1 = 1;
new ObjectOutputStream(player1.getOutputStream()).writeInt(PLAYER1);
```

Here is the client side receiving that int:

```
fromServer = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

Here is the part where I test the recieved int:

```
int player = fromServer.readInt();
if(player == PLAYER1){
 System.out.println("yy working");
}else{
  System.out.println("not working");
}
```

The problem is that neither I get an error nor system out.. 
I am using ObjectStreams and not DataStreams because of some reasons.

Comment: These snippets suggest that you are creating new streams for every message. Don't do that. It's wasteful at best and won't work at worst. Use the same streams for the life of the socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `close()` or `flush()` on server side:

```
public static int PLAYER1 = 1;
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(player1.getOutputStream());
oos.writeInt(PLAYER1);

oos.flush();

// OR

oos.close();
```

`flush()` will send any data already written to the client. This will leave you the possibility to reuse `oos`.

If you don't need `oos` anymore, call `close()`. Calling `close()` will flush any data not already sent.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't seem to survive the call `int player = fromServer.readInt();`. I would debug the call in readInt() or before that to see where it jumps out.